# Naive Bayes for GPA classification?

Tags: r, regression, classification, boruta

So I am doing a project where I have to find a method that uses a lot of both categorical and numerical variables collected from surveys to predict a child's "discretized" GPA values.

For example, the x-variables include yes/no/don't know responses to questions such as "I often get nervous about taking tests", and numerical answers such as household income. The surveys were given to teachers, caregivers, and the children themselves.

The y-variable, is GPA and ranges from 1 to 4 in discrete increments of 0.25.

What I have attempted, is to use `boruta` package to pick out the most relevant 65 features out of over 10000 features (and all of the features do make sense---they are often related to the child's behavior in school, and/or the child's scores/percentiles on standardized tests).

Then I ran a naive Bayes classifier. I do not know if this is appropriate or if there are better methods for this task, but the results are simply terrible. The model often produces extreme values such as 1 and 4, when the actual value should be somewhere in between. I thought I had relevant features for the task, but somehow the accuracy is very low.

I have also tried gradient boosting machine from `caret` package using the default parameters, but the result isn't very satisfying either.

What can I do to improve the model, and is there better methods to try?

Is regression more suited for this if I want to achieve better accuracy/minimize error?

Comment: Are you aware that this is not a classification problem? You assume that GPA 1 can depend on totally different factors then 2. Moreover, since the values are discreditized, GPA equal to 1.4999 may be something totally different than 1.5... This is a regression problem.

Comment: @Tim So you are suggesting regression because a GPA of 1.49999 might actually be the same as a GPA of 1.5? But the problem with my data set is that the GPAs are all discretized prior to me doing anything with it. Therefore there is no 1.499999 in the data set, only 1.5. If I misunderstood what you meant, please let me know. I will try regression again in the meantime.

Comment: No. What I'm saying is that you are *assuming* that the discretized GPA's are totally distinct, unordered things, so 1 is not smaller then 2 and 2 is not smaller then 3 and 1 is not closer to 2 then to 4. If you use classifier, such as NB, it doesn't care about the ordering and doesn't know that the values have any meaning, ordering, or that they are discretized. What I'm saying is that this is a regression problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Will work on regression. Do you have any other suggestion with regard with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim With regression, I ran into a problem where explanatory variables are of a mixture of numerical and categorical variables. For example, household income---those who report will have numerical value, and those who refuse to report will have "-9" as the response. Is there a way to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim I ran a linear regression with `lm` function, while converting all categorical variables into factor variables. `lm` seems to be able to handle that, and the result is significantly better than not converting. However, the accuracy is still not very good---with some predictions over 4.0. I am thinking about using some machine learning techniques such as gradient boosting machine. Do you think that will be a good idea? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a lot more regression models beyond linear regression. For ordered categorical data you have ordinal regression, for bounded continuous there is beta regression etc. You probably should start with some handbook and doing more research on available options since you seem to be considering methods not fitting for this problem.